# Div has height when empty despite min-height being 0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to style a div so that its height adjusts to fit the text inside it (providing this does not exceed its max-height). The problem is that when there is no text within the div, the div still has some height.

```css
#container {
   width: 80%;
   margin-left: 10%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
 }

 #input {
   width: 85%;
   float: left;
 }

 #submit {
   width: 15%;
   display: inline;
   float: right;
 }

 #display {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 0;
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="usr">Terminal:</label><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
    <div id="display"></div>
  </div>
```

I have also tried using `height:0; max-height:200;` but this has the same result, when there is no text within the div, it still has height and has not totally disappeared.

(I am using Bootstrap 4, in case this is relevant)

Comment: can you share full code?

Comment: overflow:scroll, right? Hm.

Comment: You may have white space inside the div, even something like a line break.

Comment: I really only see the `overflow: scroll` being the property that gives any "height" to the div; if you remove that or set it to `auto` the space is completely empty

Comment: As @IvanS95 suggested, the only "height" for `#display` is coming from the scrollbar that the browser is adding because of your `overflow: scroll` property. Unless there's other code you left out, that's your problem.

Comment: If you want a scrollbar only to appear when the content exceeds the `max-height`, you may want `overflow: auto` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Using `overflow: auto` instead of `overflow: scroll` fixed my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `padding: 0` on `#display` and try it without `overflow: auto`.
Also try `box-sizing: border-box`